# Start a css animation on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I've been looking for answers on my problem now for maybe a few weeks now and I find nothing. I'm trying to make a reaction test to check how long time it takes for the user before they react and it will popup either a square or a circle and I hit a problem...

My question is if there's any way to start an animation when the user clicks the button on the screen ?

Here's my code so far:

HTML:

```
  <div id="first-child"></div>
  <button id="Second-parent">Click me !</button>
```

CSS:

```
 #first-child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
  animation: myfirst 1s;
  }
@-webkit-animation myfirst {
    0% {background: white;}
   20% {background: white;}
   40% {background: white;}
   60% {background: white;}
   80% {background: white;}
  100% {background: red;}
  }

#second-parent {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 415px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  }
```

I prefer CSS, HTML, jQuery or Javascript. But if there's another way to do it I'll gladly hear that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
 $('#second-parent').click(function(){
  e1 = $('#first-child');
        e1.addClass('animate');
        e1.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
        function (e) {
            e1.removeClass('animate');
        });
 });
});
```

```css
 #first-child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  }
  .animate {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 3s;
  animation: myfirst 3s;
  }
@keyframes myfirst {
    0% {background: white;}
   40% {background: gray;}
   70% {background: yellow;}
  100% {background: red;}
  }
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0% {background: white;}
   40% {background: gray;}
   70% {background: yellow;}
  100% {background: red;}
  }

#second-parent {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 415px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="first-child"></div><button id="second-parent">Click me !</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#second-parent').on('click',function(){
   $('#first-child').addClass('animate');
  });
 });
```

```css
 #first-child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  }
  .animate {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 3s;
  animation: myfirst 3s;
  }
@keyframes myfirst {
    0% {background: white;}
   40% {background: gray;}
   70% {background: yellow;}
  100% {background: red;}
  }

#second-parent {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 415px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first-child"></div>
  <button id="second-parent">Click me !</button>
```

Comment: Try running this code snippet in Firefox instead of Google Chrome

Comment: It works on firefox but I need it to pop up everytime I click the button and it only work once :p

Comment: I have added a new code snippet it should work in both firefox and chrome, and also the animation will work every time you click the button not just once

Answer (score 2):

Use a css class for the animation and add the class to div when button clicked. (use `@keyframes` to define css animations.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, could you post a code so I can see what you mean it would be great if you could, um because I'm having some problem to understand sometimes... Anyway thanks for the answer I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using pure javascript and CSS `@keyframes`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>CSS Animations</title>

  <style>
/* <![CDATA[ */
div {
  height: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}

.animate {
  animation-name: slide-right;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  /* Preserve the effect of the animation at ending */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-right {

  from {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }

  50% {
    margin-left: 110px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 200px;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}

/* ]]> */
  </style>

  <script>
/* <![CDATA[ */

function DoAnimation() {
  var targetElement = document.getElementById("target");
  targetElement.className = "animate";
}
/* ]]> */
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>CSS Animations</h1>
  <div id="target">Super div</div>
  <button onclick="DoAnimation();">Go</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the -webkit-animation and animation definitions from #firstChild and instead create an "anim" class definition:

```
#first-child {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0%;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.anim{
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
    animation: myfirst 1s;
}
```

Then when you want to trigger the animation simply add the .anim class to your element with jQUery:

```
$("#first-child").addClass("anim");
```

Comment: It didn't work neither. I relized the problem in my code that it should be keyframes instead of animation. The original code is correct I wrote keyframes there but because I didn't copy the original code and I was in a little bit of hurry so it went wrong anyway sorry about that...

Answer (score 0):

Here the sample for you

```
#first-child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
  animation: myfirst 1s;
  }
@-webkit-animation myfirst {
    0% {background: white;}
   20% {background: white;}
   40% {background: white;}
   60% {background: white;}
   80% {background: white;}
  100% {background: red;}
  }

.second-parent {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 415px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  }

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#Second-parent').click(function()
    {
        $('#first-child').addClass('second-parent');
     });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="first-child"></div>
  <button id="Second-parent">Click me !</button>
</body>

</html>
```

==> please add the jquery library in the  , you can download lirabry in: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: I tried the code and it didn't worked... but I will post it here if  I find any solution

Comment: Does it have any error? You can use the console.log to know exactly.

Comment: Yeah it says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Are you add the jquery library? Missing library will be showed that  error.

Comment: I'm confused which one should I add ? I'm having some reading problems :p