# Best way to link two webpages or webapps

Tags: javascript, html, web, electron

I have created a simple webpage/app which has four buttons I use to play a sample when I am streaming games. What I am looking for is a way to get a link to another webpage which I would then add as a source to my streaming software to show an animation relating to the sound effect.

What suggestions would any of you have to make this happen? The button webpage is run locally on my PC, the animation webpage would also be run locally (or on my home server)

Any suggestions appreciated..

Comment: Load your animation webpage in an `iframe` may help.

Comment: Could you please validate the answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you are using plain HTML with (I imagine) some CSS to show content when you stream. And you want to add another HTML page contained in the project and show it when you press a button.

Is that true?

Why u dont add another HTML file in the server root or making a new folder and then just make an HTML link `<a href="newpage.html"></a>`

(I dont know If I have understand or I am already slept)

Try to copy always some code when you ask then we can read into your environment.

Edit: Remember target="_blank" atributte of the link(a) if what you want is to open the content on a new window. Maybe interesting in your scenario.

```
<a href="newpage.html" target="_blank"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a master page and linking both of your web pages to that master page. refer this.[Button Click animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543964/start-a-css-animation-on-button-click)