# Starting CSS animation by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have a CSS animation that starts when the page loads. I want it to start only when a button is pressed. I tried a few different things but it seems to only target the first circle and not them all.

HTML:

```
<div id="circles">
  <div class="circle c1">
    <div class="circle c2">
      <div class="circle c3">
          <div class="circle c4"><h3>Breathe Out</h3></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.circle h1 {
    margin:5% !important;
}

.c2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-color: white;
    animation-delay:1s;
}

.c3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: white;
    animation-delay:2s;
}

.c4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
    animation-delay:3s;
}

.c4 h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding:13%;
    font-size:24px;
    color:#1c50a8;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    border-color: #1C50A8;
  }
  24% {
    border-color: #1C50A8;
  }
  25% {
    border-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: white;
  }
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5rgLx9y0/2/)

Comment: Typically you use JavaScript to add a class in a click event handler, and the presence of that class kicks off your CSS animations.

Comment: No `<button>` element appears at linked jsfiddle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start a css animation on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543964/start-a-css-animation-on-button-click)

Comment: Above solutions use jQuery, which is not mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to the button that applies a class with the animation to your `.circle` elements.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function() {
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
   c[i].classList.add('animate');
  }
})
```

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.circle h1 {
  margin: 5% !important;
}

.c2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-color: white;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.c3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: white;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.c4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.c4 h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 13%;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #1c50a8;
}

.animate {
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    border-color: #1C50A8;
  }
  24% {
    border-color: #1C50A8;
  }
  25% {
    border-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button">
  click
</button>
<div id="circles">
  <div class="circle c1">
    <div class="circle c2">
      <div class="circle c3">
        <div class="circle c4">
          <h3>Breathe Out</h3></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `circle` `.className` from elements within `html`, `.add()` the `"circle"` `.className` to `.classList` of elements which are children of `#circles` and where `.className` begins with `"c"` at click at `<button>` element

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    this.onclick = null;
    document.querySelectorAll("#circles [class^=c]")
    .forEach(function(circle) {
      circle.classList.add("circle")
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.circle h1 {
  margin: 5% !important;
}

.c2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-color: white;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.c3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: white;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.c4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.c4 h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 13%;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #1c50a8;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    border-color: #1C50A8;
  }
  24% {
    border-color: #1C50A8;
  }
  25% {
    border-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>
click
</button>
<div id="circles">
  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
      <div class="c3">
        <div class="c4">
          <h3>Breathe Out</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $("#activate").click(function(){   
    $(".circle").each(function(index){
     $(this).css("animation-duration", "4s");    
    });
  })
})
```

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  /*animation-duration: 4s;*/
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.circle h1 {
 margin:5% !important;
}

.c2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-color: white;
 animation-delay:1s;
}

.c3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: white;
 animation-delay:2s;
}

.c4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
 animation-delay:3s;
}

.c4 h3 {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 100;
 padding:13%;
 font-size:24px;
 color:#1c50a8;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    border-color: #1C50A8;
  }
  24% {
    border-color: #1C50A8;
  }
  25% {
    border-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circles">
  <div class="circle c1">
    <div class="circle c2">
      <div class="circle c3">
          <div class="circle c4"><h3>Breathe Out</h3></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button id="activate">Animation</button>
```

you can separate the `animation-duration` CSS and put it in the button.
https://jsfiddle.net/5rgLx9y0/

```
$(function(){
  $("#activate").click(function(){      
    $(".circle").each(function(index){
        $(this).css("animation-duration", "4s");    
    });
  })
})
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#circles.anim .circle {
  animation: changeColor 4s infinite;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#circles').classList.add('anim')">
```

What this essentially does is, when the button is clicked, your parent dev `#circles` element will get the `.anim` class.

This will enable the animation on every child `.circle` element. Resulting in kicking off an animation from a click

Comment: Why the negative 1?