# Is there a way to create a css animation and link it to javascript when pressing a button

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I want to create an animation in css and then link in to javascript,
like when pressing a button to run the css animation
lets say you have:
`animation-name: vs-animation`
and `@keyframes` with the same name
and i would like it to link to `startNewRound() = true` , how would i do that

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543964/start-a-css-animation-on-button-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a CSS animation linked to JavaScript when clicking a button, you can achieve this by using JavaScript to add and remove CSS classes containing the animation. Here's how to do it step by step:

1. Define your CSS animation using `@keyframes`. For example:

```css
@keyframes vs-animation {
  0% {
    /* Initial state of the animation */
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  50% {
    /* Intermediate state of the animation */
    transform: scaleX(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    /* Final state of the animation */
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

2. In your HTML file, create a button that will call the `startNewRound()` function when clicked:

```html
<button id="startButton">Start Animation</button>
```

3. In your JavaScript file, add a click event to the button and use JavaScript to apply or remove the animation class based on the `startNewRound()` function:

```js
// Get a reference to the button and the element you want to animate
const startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
const elementToAnimate = document.getElementById("elementToAnimate");

// Add a click event to the button
startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Call the startNewRound() function or perform any other necessary logic

  // Add the CSS class with the animation
  elementToAnimate.classList.add("vs-animation");

  // Wait for the duration of the animation and then remove the class to allow it to be applied again
  setTimeout(() => {
    elementToAnimate.classList.remove("vs-animation");
  }, 1000); // Adjust the value to match the duration of your animation in milliseconds
});
```

In this example, we are adding the `vs-animation` class to the element you want to animate when the button is clicked. Then, we are removing that class after a specified time so that the animation can be restarted by clicking again.

Make sure to adjust the time in `setTimeout` to match the duration of your animation in milliseconds.

Finally, ensure that the element you want to animate has the `vs-animation` class initially so that the animation is ready to run. [anthoncode.com](https://anthoncode.com)

Comment: There is no `vs-animation` class specified your code; adding it does nothing. Since it doesn't exist I cannot say for certain, but adding it initially would run the animation, not make it ready. Also, instead of relying on a magic number for `setTimeout()`, you should use the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event)/[`animationcancel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationcancel_event) events. And, I don't see how your last link is relevant to your answer. (Perhaps you'd like to add it to your profile's bio?)

Answer (score 1):

## Web Animations API

I recommend the modern way, which would be to use the [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API): The [`element.animate()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) allows you to specify keyframes and options.

Starting a new animation cancels the previous automatically.

Example (playing a new animation per click):

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const keyframes = [
    { top: 0 },
    { top: "4rem" }
  ];
  box.animate(keyframes, { duration: 2000 });
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Start animation</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Alternative example (restarting one animation on click):

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

const animation = box.animate(
  [
    { top: 0 },
    { top: "4rem" }
  ],
  { duration: 2000 }
);
animation.cancel();

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  animation.cancel();
  animation.play();
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Start animation</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Here is an example of how you could get a `@keyframes` at-rule's keyframes using the [CSSOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model):

```js
const vsAnimation = getKeyframesOf("vs-animation");

console.log(vsAnimation);

function getKeyframesOf(animationName) {
  function collectDeclarations(keyframeRule) {
    const keyframe = { offset: parseFloat(keyframeRule.keyText) / 100 };
    for (const prop of keyframeRule.style) {
      switch (prop) {
      case "offset":
        // Exception for CSS `offset` property:
        // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Keyframe_Formats#attributes
        keyframe.cssOffset = keyframeRule.style.offset;
        break;
      default:
        keyframe[prop] = keyframeRule.style[prop];
      }
    }
    return keyframe;
  }

  let keyframesRule = null;
  for (const sheet of document.styleSheets) {
    for (const rule of sheet.cssRules) {
      if (rule instanceof CSSKeyframesRule === false) continue;
      if (rule.name !== animationName) continue;

      keyframesRule = rule;
    }
  }
  
  if (!keyframesRule) return null;

  return Array.from(keyframesRule.cssRules).map(collectDeclarations);
}
```

```css
@keyframes vs-animation {
  from { top: 0 }
  to { top: 4rem }
}
```

**Note**: It should work as intended for most cases, but I am not fully certain that it works for *every* case.

## CSS Animations

Alternatively, you can use CSS [`@keyframes` at-rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) to specify the animation's name and keyframes.

Playing the animation requires at least the name and a duration. These can be given with the [`animation` shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation), or the respective individual properties.

Example:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  box.classList.add("animated");
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes vs-animation {
  from { top: 0 }
  to { top: 4rem }
}

.animated {
  animation-name: vs-animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<button>Start animation</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

**Note**:
Web Animations API uses `"linear"` for the `easing` option by default.
CSS animations use `ease` for `animation-timing-function` by default.

Unfortunately, to enable replay we cannot simply remove then add the animation-related declarations. Before adding them back, we have to wait for a [reflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Reflow); for the browser to check for CSS changes.

Example of simply removing then adding (which does not replay the animation):

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  box.classList.remove("animated");
  box.classList.add("animated");
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes vs-animation {
  0% {
    position: relative;
    top: 0rem;
  }
  100% {
    position:relative;
    top: 2rem;
  }
}

.animated {
  animation-name: vs-animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<button>Start animation</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Changes to the CSS will automatically cause a reflow before a frame, but after JS. That means waiting for one frame before re-adding the declarations will work: See [MDN's *Run an animation again* example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Tips#run_an_animation_again).

**Note**: Generally, we have to wait for a *reflow* (the "layout engine"), not repaint (the "rendering engine"). [@AdamLeggett comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element#comment100716705_56780220) that "`requestAnimationFrame` waits for the rendering engine. [Prefer the `animate` function]; the second most technically correct is unfortunately `void element.offsetWidth`."
The `void element.offsetWidth` trick is shown below. But again, it is best to **use the Web Animations API**.

But we can cause a reflow manually as well; here is a [list of JS-related reflow causes](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a#what-forces-layout--reflow). As the link mentions:

> Generally, all APIs that synchronously provide layout metrics
> will trigger forced reflow / layout.

That means, by reading `offsetWidth` (a layout metric) we cause a reflow. The statement is often seen with `void` to discard the value, to make it conform to [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)<sup>[Can't find citation again]</sup>.

Ideally, you wouldn't manually reflow (too often), especially not in time-sensitive applications. However, it does make for arguably simpler (though more "magical") code:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  box.classList.remove("animated");
  void box.offsetHeight; // Reflow
  box.classList.add("animated");
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes vs-animation {
  0% { top: 0rem }
  100% { top: 4rem }
}

.animated {
  animation-name: vs-animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<button>Start animation</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

The Web animations API is meant for controlling animations via JS; fitting for your use case. Unfortunately, it doesn't (yet?) offer a way to convert a `@keyframes` at-rule to the [keyframe format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Keyframe_Formats) natively.

In contrast, with the approach relying on CSS animations you have to watch out for caveats (waiting for a reflow inbetween) and technicalities (`requestAnimationFrame` waiting for render, not reflow), and have to use workarounds (reading layout metrics).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find the SO page again where I read something similar to the following in an answer (and a comment quoting it): "Removing and adding in one function block doesn't work by default because the browser is single-threaded; it doesn't have the time to realize changes during the function's execution." Sounded like a **simple and easy-to-understand explanation** as to why the intuitive (but wrong) approach of simply removing then adding doesn't work. Would have liked to include a link to it.